# Reading XML files and do many action to it

Tags: javascript, xml, html

I want to read an XML files and then I want to make many action on it 
by sort it in table , and make some mathematics function 
also if any one want to find field related to any other field 
like if I have a customers , and everyone have many records 
if I write the name of my customer I will show the records related to him

shall I do that with XML and javascript and html5 only?
or I have to do it with a program language like PHP , ... ?

Comment: Do it with regexes...
(just kidding). Both languages you suggested would work.

Comment: You can also try using XSLT.

Comment: JavaScript *is* a programming language (and significantly nicer than PHP IMO).

Answer (score 0):

You're able to do this with javascript.

Jquery makes it quite simple also:
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/